# How to change the color of icon in curved navigatino bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I wanted to change the color of icon but I don't find the right code to change the color.
[image]

```
int _pageIndex = 0;
GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();
List pages = [
MyRoute(
iconData: Icons.home,
page:HomePage(),
 ),]
BottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
    key: _bottomNavigationKey,
    index: 0,
    color: Colors.indigo[700],
    buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent[100],
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds:300),
    onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _pageIndex = index; }); },),
```

Comment: What is in the MyRoute class? Can you post your code?

Comment: I found the answer ...

Comment: Note:I found the answer